# How to grab cookies from remote URL and send them back to the browser

Tags: php, android, cookies

I am building a simple php proxy that caches responses header and objects .

My problems are that if I login to youtube.com then I dont see myself as I am signed and youtube  keeps saying sign in (not signed) , but If I stop my script and just open youtube.com website then I see myself as signed . I think it is a cookies issue . Is it?

My script just grab response headers and send them back to the browser . When I use fopen() to download the object then some websites such as Google "Play STore" & "Apple Store" keeps sending HTTP 403 (Forbidden) even though I am catching the user-agent of the client through $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] and attach it with $context function stream_context_create() .. Still no luck!.

I have seen such a header Set-Cookie in a response header so I thought if I send it back to the browser using header() then it would be solved .. Still no luck.

### This is how I grab headers and send them back to the browser:

> > This is how I get cookies that are requested from the client
> >     $requested_cookie = $_COOKIE;

```
  $requested_cookie = $_COOKIE;
  $ua=  $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
  ini_set('user_agent', $ua);
  $md5_fname = md5($fname);
  $filehead = $file_path."/HTTP_HEADER/".$md5_fname.".txt";
if (file_exists($filehead)) 
{

 $handle = fopen($filehead, "r");
 $contents = fread($handle, filesize($filehead));
 $getCachedH = unserialize($contents);
 fclose($handle);
 foreach ($getCachedH as $cHead)
 {
     $sendHead = $cHead;
     $getHead = strtoupper($cHead);
     //file_put_contents("$file_path/ghassan.txt", "\n $sendHead \n" ,FILE_APPEND);
     if ( preg_match('/CONTENT-LENGTH: (\d+)/i',$getHead,$clm) ) $content_length = $clm[1];
     if ( preg_match('/CONTENT-TYPE: ([\/\w\-\d]+)/i',$getHead,$ctm) ) $content_type = $ctm[1];
     if ( preg_match('/LOCATION: (.*)/i',$cHead,$lm) ) 
     {
         $header_location = $lm[1];
         header("Location: ".$header_location);
         exit;
     }
     if ( preg_match('/^HTTP\/1\.[01] (\d\d\d)/i', $getHead, $hcm ) ) 
     {
         $http_code = $hcm[1];

     }
     header($sendHead);
  }
 }
else
{
     $opts = array(
      'http'=>array(
       'ignore_errors'=>"true",
       'method'=>"GET",
       'header'=>"Cookie: foo=bar\r\n"
       )
      );

     $context = stream_context_create($opts);
     $urlptr = fopen($_GET['url'],'rb', false, $context);
     $headers = $http_response_header;
     $http_code = $headers[0];
     if($http_code=="200")
     {
         // We grab the Response Headers and save them 
         file_put_contents($filehead, serialize($headers));
     }

     foreach ($headers as $response_header)
     {
         $sendHead = $response_header;
         $getHead = strtoupper($response_header);
         header($sendHead);
         if ( preg_match('/CONTENT-LENGTH: (\d+)/i',$getHead,$clm) ) $content_length = $clm[1];
         if ( preg_match('/CONTENT-TYPE: ([\/\w\-\d]+)/i',$getHead,$ctm) ) $content_type = $ctm[1];
        if ( preg_match('@Set-Cookie: (([^=]+)=[^;]+)@i', $sendHead , $cookm))
         {
           $sCookies = $cookm[1];
           //file_put_contents("$file_path/cookies.txt", "\n $cookm[0], $url \n" ,FILE_APPEND);
         }
         if ( preg_match('/LOCATION: (.*)/i',$sendHead,$lm) ) 
         {
             $header_location = $lm[1];
             header("Location: ".$header_location);
             exit;
         }
         if ( preg_match('/ACCEPT-RANGES: ([\w\d\-]+)/i',$getHead,$arm) ) $accept_ranges = $arm[1];
         if ( preg_match('/^HTTP\/1\.[01] (\d\d\d)/i', $getHead, $hcm ) ) 
         {
             $http_code = $hcm[1];
         } 

      }
  }
```

- Is there a function that grabs the response header + object within one call and store them together in one file ?. I don't want to use fopen() at the top of the script because Apache or Php while reading strings such as $handler = fopen($urlptr,'r'); then it connect remote URL even if i didn't call the string! which is adding latency.
- Is there a solution to access client's cookies through my php script and how to solve 403 forbidden message if I am already sending the user-agent of the Android Device when I download a file from Play Store through my script?.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I have already solved my question.

While I am grabbing remote headers of each website .. Headers already have Set-Cookie header so I resend them back to the browser and capture cookies back from $_COOKIE and add cookies with fopen() which seems to solve all my problems above.

Thank you

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: fname in /home/www/gt.php on line 6

Notice: Undefined variable: file_path in /home/www/gt.php on line 7

Notice: Undefined index: url in /home/www/gt.php on line 47

Warning: fopen(): Filename cannot be empty in /home/www/gt.php on line 47

Notice: Undefined variable: http_response_header in /home/www/gt.php on line 48

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/www/gt.php on line 56